# Unexpected warnings with case_when and regex conditions suggest too many cases are matching

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have a data set with messy date/time formatting in some hh:mm formats and Excel serial numbers. So I've coerced everything into a string and I'm using `stringr` and `readr` within a large `case_when` block to identify different formats and process them properly. I think I'm misunderstanding either my `stringr` functions or `case_when` because I'm getting the output I expect, but it's throwing warnings of parsing failures and `NA` coercion that aren't in the final product.

Here are some dummy data with an example of each of the formats in my data set:

```
dummy <- tibble(x = c("13:15:21", "02:03:17+01:00", "12:03", "0.1234"))
```

I've made a function to identify and parse each of these formats. It calls on another function to change excel serial codes into times. It uses regular expressions which I think are correct, but to summarise:

- `^0\\.` should identify Excel serial numbers by the fact they are all
  decimals <1
- `\\+` is identifying the times with the DST timezone
  indicator by searching for the plus sign then
- `.+(?=\\+)` is
  extracting everything before the plus sign to parse
- `:` is testing
  for a colon to make sure the result is some kind of time. This is a
  broader test so it's coming last after the pluses have already been
  matched

```
convert_times <- function(x){
  case_when(str_detect(x, "^0\\.")        ~ convert_excel_time(x), 
            str_detect(x, "\\+")          ~ parse_time(str_extract(x, ".+(?=\\+)")), 
            str_detect(x, ":")            ~ parse_time(x),
            .default = NA)
}

convert_excel_time <- function(x){
  as.numeric(x) * 24 * 60 * 60 %>%
  as_datetime() %>% 
  hms::as_hms()
}
```

When I run it, I get the expected output, but the warnings that come along with it suggest to me I'm not understanding what's happening under the hood.

```
> dummy %>% 
+   mutate(new = convert_time(x))
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  x              new        
  <chr>          <time>     
1 13:15:21       13:15:21.00
2 02:03:17+01:00 02:03:17.00
3 12:03          12:03:00.00
4 0.1234         02:57:41.76
```

These are my errors

```
[[1]]
<warning/rlang_warning>
Warning in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `new = convert_time(x)`.
Caused by warning in `convert_excel_time()`:
! NAs introduced by coercion
---
Backtrace:
    ▆
 1. ├─dummy %>% mutate(new = convert_time(x))
 2. ├─dplyr::mutate(., new = convert_time(x))
 3. └─dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(., new = convert_time(x))

[[2]]
<warning/rlang_warning>
Warning in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `new = convert_time(x)`.
Caused by warning:
! 2 parsing failures.
row col   expected         actual
  2  -- time like  02:03:17+01:00
  4  -- time like  0.1234        
---
Backtrace:
    ▆
 1. ├─dummy %>% mutate(new = convert_time(x))
 2. ├─dplyr::mutate(., new = convert_time(x))
 3. └─dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(., new = convert_time(x))
```

It seems to me, `convert_time` shouldn't be trying to parse those two observations at all since they are excluded by the left side of the `case_when` block. Similarly, I didn't expect `NA` coercion since the left hand side of the `case_when` prevents `convert_excel_time()` from seeing the hh:mm strings. Many thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing here, but does `case_when` run each of the functions on the entire set of data, and only then subset them afterwards for output (it looks suspiciously like that in the code)? That would make sense in the context of the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gah! I didn't read all the documentation. The `dplyr` reference (https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html) clearly says `case_when` always solves all the RHS equations, which is why they throw a warning, but only uses the ones that match the LHS conditions.

```
# `case_when()` evaluates all RHS expressions, and then constructs its
# result by extracting the selected (via the LHS expressions) parts.
# In particular `NaN`s are produced in this case:
y <- seq(-2, 2, by = .5)
case_when(
  y >= 0 ~ sqrt(y),
  .default = y
)
#> Warning: NaNs produced
#> [1] -2.0000000 -1.5000000 -1.0000000 -0.5000000  0.0000000  0.7071068
#> [7]  1.0000000  1.2247449  1.4142136
```